# Adobe AEM 6.0 component default control

Tags: adobe, aem

When building components in AEM, by default new components are created with an associated JSP file for rendering.

For builds using Sightly, each time a component is created the developer must delete the JSP file and create the required HTML file.

This leads to wasted time and effort, not to mention frustration for developers having to complete a repetitive task.

Can AEM be configured so the default rendering generated is HTML rather than JSP?

Thank you

Comment: The question for me is why are you developing directly in CRXDE and not just create normal project, edit the files with your preferred editor (e.g. eclipse) and [setup maven](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html) for the deployment to your local CQ instance

Comment: Thanks d33t that's a valid point and I agree. However I'm still curious if this is something which can be configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a configuration is possible in AEM, primarily because, the creation of component and its JSP is handled through Javascript.

```
/crx/de/js/CRX/plugins/action/CreateComponentAction.js
```

Even the initial content available within the JSP file is populated through this JS only.

A short snippet from the JS, is shown here

```js
// create component JSP
var nodeName = label + ".jsp";
var compJspFile = CRX.Util.createNode(nodeName, nodeName, 
                                CRX.util.NT_FILE, component, loader);
```